# How do I wrap a rogue function with a timeout?

Tags: c#, task

I've got a function in a 3rd party library that occasionally goes rogue and never returns.  Something like so:

```
    // This is 3rd party function so I can't make it take a cancellation token.
    public void RogueFunction()
    {

        while (true)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("sleeping...");
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
    }
```

I'd like to wrap it in a task with a timeout which is easy enough to do with a 'task.Wait(mills)'.  While this returns control to me after the timeout, it doesn't actually kill the task.

In the code below, the rogue function continues to log after the timeout.

```
    [Fact]
    public void Test()
    {
        var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(RogueFunction);
        var complete = task.Wait(500);
        if (!complete)
        {
            // how do I kill the task so that it quits logging?
            Thread.Sleep(5000);

            task.Dispose();  // Throws exception: A task may only be disposed if it is in a completion state (RanToCompletion, Faulted or Canceled).
        }
    }
```

How do I completely kill this task, so that I can retry it without ending up with a bunch of them running infinitely on my background thread pool.

Comment: Use a cancellation token to cancel the task after a set amount of time

Comment: Unfortunately, cancellation token has same effect as task.Wait(timeout).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that [`Thread.Abort`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.abort) is your only option. If you are afraid that doing so may leave the application in a corrupted state (open file handles etc), then the safest option is to run the thread in a different process, and then [kill the process](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1560567/11178549). Another workable solution is to run the thread in a different AppDomain, and then abort the thread and [unload the AppDomain](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part4.aspx#_Ending_Application_Domains).

Comment: Hmm..  I was trying to avoid that but thanks for confirming that I'm not missing something from the task based approach.

Comment: Yes, as far as I know Tasks are based on the principal of cooperation. When something goes rogue, there is no polite way of making it behave.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias - I would have lead with the "different process" option as it is the only safe way to go. Even using a separate `AppDomain` isn't safe when calling `Thread.Abort()` - it can corrupt the calling `AppDomain` too.

Comment: @Enigmativity agreed. Thread.Abort is the easiest to implement though. Sometimes you can be sure that aborting a thread is safe, because you can inspect the source code and assert that no unmanaged resources are going to leak.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED**:

Let one has such a function:

```
static class Rogue
{
    // This is 3rd party function so I can't make it take a cancellation token.
    public static void RogueFunction()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("RogueFunction works");
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

Possible solution is to wrap it with a class like this:

```
public class InfiniteAction
{
    private readonly Action action;
    private CancellationTokenSource cts;
    private Thread thread;

    public InfiniteAction(Action action) => this.action = action;

    public void Join() => thread?.Join();

    public void Start()
    {
        if (cts == null)
        {
            cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
            thread = new Thread(() => action());
            thread.IsBackground = true;
            thread.Start();
            cts.Token.Register(thread.Abort);
        }
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        if (cts != null)
        {
            cts.Cancel();
            cts.Dispose();
            cts = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Now one can start an infinite action like `InfiniteAction.Start()` and stop it like `InfiniteAction.Stop()`.

It could be done manually:

```
void ManualCancelation()
{
    var infiniteAction = new InfiniteAction(Rogue.RogueFunction);
    Console.WriteLine("RogueFunction is executing.");
    infiniteAction.Start();

    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to stop it.");
    Console.ReadKey();
    Console.WriteLine();
    infiniteAction.Stop();

    Console.WriteLine("Make sure it has stopped and press any key to exit.");
    Console.ReadKey();
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Or by timer:

```
void ByTimerCancelation()
{
    var interval = 3000;
    var infiniteAction = new InfiniteAction(Rogue.RogueFunction);
    Console.WriteLine($"RogueFunction is executing and will be stopped in {interval} ms.");
    Console.WriteLine("Make sure it has stopped and press any key to exit.");
    infiniteAction.Start();
    var timer = new Timer(StopInfiniteAction, infiniteAction, interval, -1);
    Console.ReadKey();
    Console.WriteLine();
}

private void StopInfiniteAction(object action)
{
    var infiniteAction = action as InfiniteAction;
    if (infiniteAction != null)
        infiniteAction.Stop();
    else
        throw new ArgumentException($"Invalid argument {nameof(action)}");
}
```

Comment: Calling `Thread.Abort()` is unsafe. The only time it should ever be called is when you're trying to forcibly exit from the app.

Comment: Code only answers are also frowned on unless the code is super obvious. I think yours needs some serious explanation.

Comment: @Enigmativity, in this case it's a background thread encapsulated in a class, so it's not so evil for it's the only possible solution (here i agree with Theodor Zoulias's answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/55885754/10958092). What would you suggest?

Comment: @Enigmativity, I broke the code into parts. Each should be pretty obvious.

Comment: @Alex there is a race condition in your code. The `CancellationTokenSource` could be cancelled before the thread is started, causing the not-yet-started thread to abort, causing a `ThreadStartException`. You'd better switch the order of the commands `cts.Token.Register(t.Abort)` and  `t.Start()`. Also you could keep a reference of the thread inside the `InfiniteAction` class, so that you can `Join` with the aborted thread after `cts.Cancel()`.

Comment: @Alex - Calling `Thread.Abort()` can corrupt the run-time causing the rest of your threads to not be reliable. It's not safe at all.

Comment: @Enigmativity could you provide a link or code that demonstrates corruption of the run-time, after aborting a thread that alternates between writing in the `Console` and sleeping?

Comment: @Theodor Zoulias, good idea about race condition and exposing some functionality of the encapsulated thread. I think the class may be improved in many ways.